# String problems for easy68k

Tags: easy68k

I am looking for some help with a 68k program I am creating. I was wondering how to print each line separate string that i have defined as:

```
          str
           dc.b '   #     '
           dc.b '  # #    '
           dc.b ' #   #   '
           dc.b '#     #  '
           dc.b '#######  '
           dc.b '#     #  '
           dc.b '#     #  '
```

Currently my program prints it out to all 1 line. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appricated as i am completely stuck on it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want to do is to add `,CR,LF` to each line ending to produce a carriage return and a linefeed.

I found [similar code here](http://www.easy68k.com/QuickStart/LoadPageFrames.htm).

You also need to define what CR and LF are:

```
CR EQU $0D
LF EQU $0A
```

Comment: i know that's one way but what if im not allowed to edit or add any additional codes to the message? is there any other way to separate the line?